# Error using AudioToolbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, runtime-error, audiotoolbox

I am working on an App using AudioToolbox. From time to time when I launch the application I get an error in AudioToolbox initialisation phase.

```
2017-10-11 16:28:05.649918+0200 [aurioc] 1707: AURemoteIO@0x103042840: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004002
```

Commenting code seems the problem happens when I call:

```
status = AudioOutputUnitStart(self.audioUnit);
status = AudioOutputUnitStop(self.audioUnit);
```

Does anyone know where is the reason of that problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A bit late, but did you find the cause of the problem?

Comment: Not really .....